# vb.net - Make two strings in one string

Tags: vb.net, duplicates

So for example:

```
Dim str1 = "{goat}{ball}{troll}"
Dim str2 = "{apple}{goat}{troll}"
```

then I would like to remove the duplicates and see something like this:

```
Dim str3 = "{goat}{ball}{troll}{apple}"
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: What's your framework version? System.Linq is what I would use. (after splitting the text strings into enumerables)

Comment: .NET Framework 4.5, okay I try it thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim Delimiters As Char() = "}{".ToCharArray ' Or: {"}"c, "{"c}

Dim str1 As String = "{goat}{ball}{troll}"
Dim str2 As String = "{apple}{goat}{troll}"
Dim str3 As String = String.Empty

Dim UniqueItems As List(Of String) =
    (str1 & str2).Split(Delimiters, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).
                  Distinct.ToList

str3 = String.Format("{{{0}}}", String.Join(CStr(Delimiters), UniqueItems))
```

Resulting string:

```
{goat}{ball}{troll}{apple}
```